# Little regular expression on js

Tags: javascript

I am new in regular expressions. I have the variable that contains:

```
<b><font color="#32748">My string:</font></b>
<big>  My value </big>
<br>
```

Its string in varible repeating multiple times with changing of `My string` and `My value`(random value). I need to find `My value` of concrete `My string` and store (value) in new varible. Sometimes that string has spaces, sometimes without space.

Comment: don't parse dom with regular expressions. maybe look into xpath instead?

Comment: don't ask for code .. show the code which is having defect..!!

Comment: Wow. A `font` tag. Where did you find _that_ one?

Comment: I parse it from old site

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags. tl;dr: what @Kris said

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really [try to avoid using regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Especially with very powerful tools to do so built right into every browser.

Here is a solution with no regular expressions, I find it pretty simple.

Here is how it works:

- We create an HTML element
- The  browser already contains a very good HTML parser :) It handles edge cases like spaces in the name, escaped entities, and partial HTML for us just like it does for web pages. We dump the HTML in the element.
- We can query the element using the querySelector syntax, or even simpler getElementsByTagName if you're an old fashined guy.
- We use the `textContent` property to obtain the text.

Actual code:

```
var test = '<b><font color="#32748">My string:</font></b><big>  My value </big><br>';

// we create an empty element and put the html in it
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = test;

// get the text from the font tag, as you asked for.
var test = div.querySelector("font").textContent;
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGfYK/)

Note, `<font>` tags are deprecated and should not be used in new code. I'd consider checking out the current HTML5 spec and seeing how things work in modern HTML.

Note2, in oldIE you can't use `textContent` so you can do `innerHTML` or `innerText`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myRegEx = /<b><font color="#[0-9]{3,6}">(.+)<\/font><\/b>[\r\n]{0,2}<big>(.+)<\/big>[\r\n]{0,2}<br>/i;
var myString = '<b><font color="#32748">My string:</font></b>\n<big>  My value     </big>\n<br>';
var myResult = myString.match(myRegEx);
console.log(myResult[1] + " | " + myResult[2]);
```

RegEx:
`[0-9]` Matches any single character in the range 0-9.
`{3,6}` Matches 3 to 6 of the preceeding token.
`(.+)` Capture group.
`.` Matches any character, except for line breaks if dotall is false.
`+` Matches 1 or more of the preceeding token.
`\n` Line break character.
`\r` Carriage return character.
`[\r\n]` Match any single character in the set.
`{0,2}` Matches 0 to 2 of the preceeding token.

Now just apply it in your code. You can test it at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery for something like this:

```
var t = '<b><font color="#32748">My string:</font></b><big>  My value </big><br><b><font color="#32748">My string1:</font></b><big>  My value1 </big><br>';

var data = $('big', $('<div/>').append(t)).map(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text());
});

console.log(data[0]);  // My value 
console.log(data[1]);  // My value1
```

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery? Answering with jQuery code in non-jquery questions is generally frowned upon in StackOverflow. See [this very related question in Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)